# Bypassing Full authentication is required - Spring

Tags: spring, rest, authentication

I have an issue. I built a Spring(+REST, AngularJS, Java and that's about the most important technologies used) application(using JHipster), but I have some difficulties testing it. I try to run requests using Postman(http://localhost:8080/api/users, for example, which is a URI generated by default when you build your JHipster application), but I get the "Full authentication is required to access this resource error". Now I imagine that this could be bypassed by using some sort of token, but I was wondering if there was something I could do to get rid of this. I mean, for example, if I wanted http://localhost:8080/api/users to be accessible without having to log in, you know, display the whole list of users on a website page to everyone, not only to those that have an account, what would I need to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use microservices with JHipster, each microservice has `MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration`. There you have an overriden `configure` method which usually has a part like:

```
.and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/profile-info").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

You can define `/api/users` similar to `api/profile-info`. You can also play with permissions in this file and so on.

And something like this surely exists for a monolith app.

Comment: I don't have mircoservices, but I still found a class SecurityConfiguration which holds the configure method and it worked!!! Thanks a lot, man!